# Aircraft with large, double orange lights at night

Tags: aircraft-identification, aircraft-external-lights

**Question:**

I saw an aircraft flying over, about two hours after sunset with a pair of bright, large, constantly on, orange lights. I'm wondering what kind of aircraft this could have been.

**More details:**

- Latitude - Longitude: 43.1, 25.4 (central Bulgaria)
- Date: 8 August 2021
- Time (approximately): 22:30 EEST (Sofia, Bulgaria)
- Estimated direction: flying from NNE to SSW
- Estimated height: unsure, but I'm guessing at least several kilometers up (see below)

**Additional information:**

We were stargazing with a group of adults and children, looking north towards the Perseus constellation, looking out for meteors from the Perseids meteor shower.

At some point we saw two bright orange lights approaching from the north at a constant speed. They were not blinking, but permanently on. They were also quite large (not the blinking green/red dots I'm used to seeing on airliners). And we could see them as round shapes, much bigger than stars or planets, but much smaller than the moon. They appeared about the size of the tip of a pencil eraser. The craft passed straight overhead and then continued flying in a straight line until it disappeared out of sight. I estimate we were able to see it for at least a minute. We were able to see a good portion of the night sky from our location, I estimate at least 120 degrees. We didn't hear any sound coming off it and with the naked eye there were no other lights. However, looking with binoculars, a regularly flashing white light was visible between the orange lights. This light was set a fraction to the rear of the craft, but more or less between the orange lights.

The orange lights appeared to me as circles all the time, while the craft was coming towards us, while overhead, and while flying away from us. So in my mind they must have been sphere shaped.

I checked where the ISS was at that time with this [ISS Tracker](http://www.isstracker.com/historical) and it appears that was above northwest Australia, so nowhere near.

What kind of aircraft could this have been?

Comment: related: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/63851/what-type-of-aircraft-would-fly-with-an-orange-light-at-night

Comment: Aircraft do not have blinking green lights. Not if they are functioning properly at least :) Blinking lights are either red (beacon) or white (strobe).

Comment: @Jamiec - thank you. Yes I'd seen and considered that question and its answers, but none seem satisfactory.

Comment: @Jpe61 - thank you. So the green lights are always static? I didn't know that. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Typically aircraft have three types of lights: static (always on) **nav lights**: red shown to front and left, green shown to front and right, and white shown to rear sector. **Beacon**: a blinking (or rotating type) red light shown to all directions. This/these are kept on when engines are running, or plane is about to start. **Strobe light(s)**: high power white blinker light shown all direction. Strobes are the most visible light, can be seen from great distances (>100km). Typically switched on when entering the runway for takeoff, and shut off when taxiing off the runway after landing

Comment: ... and of course landing- and taxi lights, which are self explanatory. Is it possible you saw a plane approaching an airfield for landing? The lights might have been landing lights? Some planes have multiple landing lights, in wings for example.

Comment: Thank you for explaining @Jpe61. I know a bit more about aircraft lights now. The one I saw didn't have any red or green lights (that I could see at least). With the naked eye I only saw the orange lights at the sides (I'm assuming these were at the sides - at the ends of the wings, but I couldn't see the actual aircraft, so not certain) and no strobe light. With binoculars I did see a strobe light that appeared to be in the center of the aircraft (on the underside). I also didn't hear it, which all suggests the aircraft was very high.

Comment: I looked up the nearest airfields. There are some small ones around, but quite far away. One about 50 kilometres to the northwest. Another about 20 kilometres to the east. And a third one about 40 kilometres to the south. This is new territory for me, but to me the aircraft seemed to be cruising.

Comment: I'm kinda veering in the direction of this being some sort of a drone.

Comment: @Jpe61 Hmm, yes perhaps. What would be your thinking behind it? And 'some sort', what kind of type/purpose would you think?

Comment: Just the fact that if it was a legitimate "real" acft, it would have had the standard light setup. There are no exception to that.

Comment: If a multi-rotor drone had amber LEDs on two of its rotors, that would explain why the lights appeared basically circular to observers throughout multiple viewing angles. And drones are quiet, and their height would be very difficult to gauge at night.

Comment: Thank you @ CCTO, that makes sense. I've been looking into drones and there are so many types; I had no idea. @Jpe61's suggestion that it was some sort of drone starts to make sense. From the size and the distance it travelled I'd think it would have been a commercial or military drone. No idea why it would have those orange lights though. And also, if drones fly around like that wouldn't it be good if they had the same navigations lights as airplanes?

Comment: @CCTO -- are there any known examples of multi-rotor drones with lights on rotor tips?

Comment: Could this have been some sort of craft based on two balloons?  Maybe even two "fire balloons" joined together with a light between?

Comment: Re "From the size and the distance it travelled I'd think it would have been a commercial or military drone. " -- on clear nights (and note that the OP was stargazing) an inversion layer often sets up in the lower atmosphere, inhibiting mixing and allowing there to be strong winds aloft, but little or no wind at the surface.  Hence a balloon just a few hundred feet up could travel much faster than you might expect based on the wind felt at ground level.

Answer (score 1):

The large size of the orange lights you saw-- "much bigger than stars or planets"-- suggests two [fire balloons](https://midimagic.sgc-hosting.com/candbal.htm) joined together, with a blinking white light between.  The lack of sound is also consistent with this.  For a powered aircraft to be flying so high that you couldn't hear the engine, and the lights to still appear "much bigger than stars or planets" from your vantage point, the lights would have to be enormous, which is implausible.

Note that on clear nights, a temperature inversion layer often sets up in the lower atmosphere, inhibiting mixing and allowing there to be strong winds aloft but little or no wind at the surface. Hence a balloon just a few hundred feet up-- or a few thousand feet up-- could travel much faster than you might expect based on the wind felt at ground level.

Comment: This sounds like a plausible explanation, but I have a few questions about it. The page you shared talks about using candles for the balloon, which would cause the air in the balloons to heat up. If candles were involved I'd expect some flickering in the lights, which I don't remember seeing. Although, if a prankster had made this and put a white flashing light in the middle, they could have also made larger lights at the sides. Also, it was going in such a straight line - like a ruler. Wouldn't you expect wind to cause some lateral movement? I appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: @Dvaeer If what you saw was indeed two fire balloons, then they would have been completely still relative to the air, so there would be no relative wind to make them flicker. Likewise, their direction of motion would have been directly in line with the wind, so unless the wind suddenly changed for some reason, their flight path would be a straight line.